# Css Positioning/ responsive design within a Widget -like design

Tags: html, css

I currently have [This](http://jsfiddle.net/bmouxLwu/) in which is going to be part of my 'widget view of tanks. I wish to style/format my design to be similar to:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| HEADER                                 X |
+------------------------------------------+
|  ______________________________________  |
| <______________________________________> |
|  |                % full              |  |
|  |                                    |  |
|  |WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|  |  <-- tank fills its container, should be centered  
|  |       O         o       O          |  |      hoz. shouldn't overflow box
|  ___________o_____________________O____  |
| <______________________________________> |
|                                          |
|  +------------------------------------+  |
|  |                                    |  |
|  |             TABULAR DATA           |  |
|  |                here                |  |  <-- table has 100% width (working)
|  |                                    |  |
|  +------------------------------------+  |
+------------------------------------------+
| FOOTER                                   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

I am having issues with the internal layout here, where due to the way i've createed the shape of my tank, it is hard to position it at the top of the page.

How could i create the layout like above, where the tank and table fill the main part of the widget, and have no overlapping of the 'widget's containing walls'?

```css
     .tankWidget {
       position: relative;
       width: 45%;
       height: 400px;
       float: left;
       background-color: #c4c4c4;
       margin: 1.5%;
     }
     .banner {
       min-height: 40px;
       width: 100%;
       background-color: #383838;
       color: #ececec;
       margin: 0;
     }
     .widget-footer {
       min-height: 40px;
       width: 100%;
       background-color: #383838;
       bottom: 0;
       position: absolute;
       color: #ececec;
     }
     #container {
       margin: 0;
       margin-top: -50px;
       width: 100%;
       padding: 0;
       -moz-perspective: 1000px;
       /*required to make cylinder shape*/
       -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
     }
     #frame {
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(125px, 70px, 50px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translate3d(125px, 70px, 50px);
     }
     .strip {
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     }
     .strip div {
       position: fixed;
       background: blue;
       background-repeat: repeat;
       border-width: thin 10px;
       height: 120px;
       /*height and width of tank display*/
       width: 34px;
     }
     .strip div:before {
       border-bottom: 2px solid black;
       content: "";
       position: absolute;
       z-index: -1;
       /*Make this lower so any text appears in front*/
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       bottom: 50%;
       /*used for tank level setting*/
       left: 0;
       background: green;
     }
     .strip .a {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .b {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(15deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .c {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(124px);
     }
     .strip .d {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .e {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .f {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(75deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .g {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .h {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(105deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .i {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .j {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(135deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .k {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .l {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(165deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .m {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .n {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(195deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .o {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .p {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(225deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .q {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .r {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(255deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .s {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .t {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(285deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .u {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .v {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(315deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .w {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(124px)
     }
     .strip .x {
       border-top: 1px solid black;
       border-bottom: 1px solid black;
       -moz-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);
       -webkit-transform: rotateY(345deg) translateZ(124px);
     }
```

```html
<div class="tankWidget">
  <div class="banner">Tank 1: Kero</div>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="frame">
      <div class="strip">
        <div class="a">50% Full</div>
        <div class="b"></div>
        <div class="c"></div>
        <div class="d"></div>
        <div class="e"></div>
        <div class="f"></div>
        <div class="g"></div>
        <div class="h"></div>
        <div class="i"></div>
        <div class="j"></div>
        <div class="k"></div>
        <div class="l"></div>
        <div class="m"></div>
        <div class="n"></div>
        <div class="o"></div>
        <div class="p"></div>
        <div class="q"></div>
        <div class="r"></div>
        <div class="s"></div>
        <div class="t"></div>
        <div class="u"></div>
        <div class="v"></div>
        <div class="w"></div>
        <div class="x"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <table id="specTab1">
    <tr>
      <th>Volume:</th>
      <td>50L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Capacity:</th>
      <td>100L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ullage (AL):</th>
      <td>1.24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <br />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="widget-footer"></div>
</div>
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong with the need for the line breaks to achieving this currently.

Any help would be much appreciated here.

**Please note**

the **height** of the widget is unlikely to change. However, the width may depending on the width of screen (hence use of %'s instead of px)

[image]

What I would like to have is a **responsive** design like:

[image: this]

The Table is actually going to be a KendoGrid in which does a lot of the styling already for it.

[linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26991591/creating-a-dynamic-tank-level-meter-using-html-and-css) where i am looking to make this dynamic

Comment: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/bmouxLwu/2/) Do u mean this?

Comment: @user3801433 your demo gives edited image when width made smaller. I need to to 'fit widget width'(shrink width to size) (It's also brought the tank up too much).

Comment: It cannot be done with css nd html alone. I think u need JS or JQuery

Comment: I'm about 80% sure it *is* possible with pure css, however my head is that fried I can't think (currently) how.

Comment: ok jbutler483, I ll try nd tell you later coz i am little busy. I hope somebody could help you before me.

Comment: have you considered a different markup approach for the tank itself? I mean I think the tank can be done faster with a different markup

Comment: I've it set up currently so I can add animation @Crispy-George so I don't think that's a possibility here. (the tank will spin in 3d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by applying transformations to elements you implicit (absolute) positioning. Thus, since the container and frame elements do not have a set height you needed to add extra line breaks to position the table.

Since you have a fixed height for the widget, you can set an absolute position on that table:

```
#specTab1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px; // to leave space for the 40px footer
}
```

Next thing is the tank itself. The widget's width is set relative (40%) but the translateZ and width values of the individual strip are fixed.

```
.strip div {
    ...
    width:34px;
    ...
}
.strip .a {
    ...
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(124px);
    ...
}
```

These two values are of course important to actually render a cylindric object but due to the fixed values this doesn't adapt very well. Main problem is the missing z axis reference which doesn't allow you to use relative units, `translateX(100%)` or even `translateY(calc(50% + 15px))` work fine, but this is not the case for `translateZ()`.

Long story short, imho pure CSS currently doesn't allow you to render your tank in a responsive way. You will most probably need javascript to get the actual width of the widget (in absolute numbers) and calculate the values for each strip. This could be done with a function like this (this only sets the webkitTransform, you need to do that for other prefixes as well):

```
    function resize3d() {
        var container = document.getElementById('container');
        w = container.offsetWidth / 10;
        z = container.offsetWidth / 30 * 11;
        var grad = 0;
        var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx";
        for(var i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++)
        {
            var letter = alphabet.charAt(i);
            var el = document.querySelector(".strip ."+letter);
            el.style.width = w+"px";
            el.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY("+grad+"deg) translateZ("+z+"px)";
            grad += 15;
        }
    }
```

See the ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bmouxLwu/9/)*** (written for webkit, only) for yourself and resize the window. I also adjusted quite a few of your transform values to make the tank more or less centered for the spinning animation (try hovering the tank! ;) or get it [started automatically](http://jsfiddle.net/bmouxLwu/11/)).

Comment: Thanks for the compliments, but that's just a draft. It has issues when screen is too narrow. And you probably need to adjust the calculations. But I guess, you got the general idea of what I did. ;)

Comment: it's much further than I got (as you can tell :P) I've already tested and it goes (hopefully) as small as the smallest screen i'll need it to be used for. Thank you for this!)